# Read and write to an Excel file (xlsx) containing pre-established formulas with php

Tags: php, excel, xlsxwriter

I want to read data from an Excel file (xlsx), replace some cells with values ​​to allow cells with formulas to automatically calculate and generate another Excel file as output from the given result

I tried to use [Box\Spout](https://opensource.box.com/spout/docs/) but it doesn't recognize the formulas

Comment: Take a look at [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it may or may not help you

Comment: I can also recommend phpoffice/phpspreadsheet, it works great